# How to make moving and connected dots in?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make something like this,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elHqinIm4RI

but in c#.

I want to have e.g. 100 dots, that start at random positions and then move in an also random direction at first. When they collide with a side from form they should bounce off. So it is similar to the ball in pong.
And all dots that are in a given radius of other dots should draw a line between them that only cuts off when the distance between them exceeds the radius given.

```
int i = 0;
Random rndm = new Random();
Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
```

This only draws dots at random positions, but I think that this won't get me where I want it to get me

```
for (; i < 3456; i++) 
{
  e.Graphics.FillEllipse(aBrush, rndm.Next(0, 801), rndm.Next(0, 601), 3, 3);
  //Thread.Sleep(1); //allows for smoother buildup
}
```

Comment: Can you find some way to get the entire question into the post? Many of us don't want to watch a video, click links and some can't. Additionally, links die on the internet. Something more permanent is better.

Comment: Animations in winforms? (vomiting sound) Render GIF and show it in `PictureBox`.

Comment: I already thought of putting only a GIF in but this is not really what I want. I want to do it without a GIF, because I want to improve my skills with drawing on forms and I need to have access on the animation progress, later I want to have some modifications. Like that the the dots should only connect if they are in a certain range form the cursor, this will not work with a GIF.

Comment: Your code won't work because drawing your way is fire and forget.  That is, once it draws the circle, nothing in your program tells you where that circle is.  Put the circles in a List<Rectangle> variable so you can track them.  Eventually, you will probably have to modify that Rectangle class with your own class to track more information about each circle.  Your question here is too broad.

Comment: You will also have to define the user interaction you want. And: No, Winforms is terribly bad at creating smooth animations as it doesn't help you with synch'ing the drawing with the monitor refreshs. But you can go ahead with it and later add an option to store frames into gifs..

Answer (score 1):

Agreed...WinForms is not the best choice for this type of application.

With that said, here's some **HORRIBLY INEFFICIENT** code to get you started:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int radius = 6;
    private int jiggleDistance = 3;      
    private int numberOfDots = 100;
    private Random R = new Random();
    private int lineDistanceThreshold = 50;
    private List<Point> dots = new List<Point>();
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateDots();
        tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
        tmr.Interval = 100;
        tmr.Start();
    }

    private void populateDots()
    {
        dots.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDots; i++)
        {
            Point dot = new Point(
                R.Next(radius, this.ClientRectangle.Width - radius),
                R.Next(radius, this.ClientRectangle.Height - radius));
            dots.Add(dot);
        }
    }

    private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < dots.Count; i++)
        {
            Point dot = dots[i];
            dot.Offset(R.Next(-1, 2) * jiggleDistance, R.Next(-1, 2) * jiggleDistance);
            if (dot.X < radius)
            {
                dot = new Point(radius, dot.Y);
            }
            if (dot.X > this.ClientRectangle.Width - radius)
            {
                dot = new Point(this.ClientRectangle.Width - radius, dot.Y);
            }
            if (dot.Y < radius)
            {
                dot = new Point(dot.X, radius);
            }
            if (dot.Y > this.ClientRectangle.Height - radius)
            {
                dot = new Point(dot.X, this.ClientRectangle.Height - radius);
            }
            dots[i] = dot;
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // connecting lines: *very ineffecient, draws lines twice
        foreach(Point dot in dots)
        {
            foreach(Point otherDot in dots)
            {
                if (otherDot != dot)
                {
                    if(dotToDotDistance(dot, otherDot) <= lineDistanceThreshold)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, dot, otherDot);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // dots on top of lines:
        foreach (Point dot in dots)
        {
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(dot, new Size(1, 1));
            rc.Inflate(radius, radius);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, rc);
        }
    }

    private double dotToDotDistance(Point ptA, Point ptB)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(ptB.X - ptA.X, 2) + Math.Pow(ptB.Y - ptA.Y, 2));
    }

}
```

Screen shot of jiggling dots with connecting lines:
[image]

Comment: By now U understand that winform is not the best choice for this, but I wanted to make this animation , thank you for your efford